# What's the term for constructing a line segment longer than a given ruler?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I'm looking for a very specific term related to the practical application of elementary geometry.

## Geometric Description

**The Problem:** Having a ruler of finite length, construct a segment longer that that ruler.

**The Solution:**

1. Using the given ruler, mark the starting point of a ruler as $A$, and the ending point of a ruler as $B$.
2. Construct a segment $AB$.
3. Let $C$ be the point on segment $AB$, not coinscident with neither $A$ nor $B$ (simply said, let $C$ be the point on $AB$ that lies between $A$ and $B$).
4. Align the start of the ruler with the point $C$, and the ruler itself with the line $CB$.
5. Mark the **new** ending point of a ruler as $D$.
6. Construct a segment $BD$.

That way, we've got a segment $AD$ longer than the ruler, which solves the problem.

## Practical Use

The similar trick, **the term for which I am looking for**, is used to construct straight lines on a ground, for example, when building a railroad or power supply lines. In that scenario, the problem is to construct a straight line on the ground that will pass through two given points. For the sake of completeness we'll also assume there are two people, named **Alice** and **Bob**.

To achieve the goal, the given points $A$ and $B$ are marked by long pegs. Alice stands at one of these pegs, for example, at the peg at a point $A$, looking at the peg at a point $B$. Then Bob chooses the position for the third peg carefully so that it obstructs Alice's view of the peg at a point $B$. This might require a good illustration for proper understanding, so I'm providing one.

[image: The case when we need to put more pegs on the given line]

Needless to say, this requires both initial pegs to be placed vertically, which can be checked with an adjusting tool, just as shown on the image below.

[image: Making sure the pegs are perfectly vertical]

Another possible scenario is that the segment $AB$, marked by the vertical pegs, needs to be extended further, which means that instead of placing the third peg somewhere between them, we need to place it in a way that one of the initial pegs will lie between the other one and the new one, so that all three pegs will be on the same line. Then, to make sure that the third peg is placed correctly, Alice stands at a peg at a point $A$, and Bob puts a new peg at some point $C$, chosen in a way that the peg at a point $B$ will obstruct Bob's view of the peg at a point $A$ and, at the same time, will obstruct Alice's view of the peg at a point $C$. Once again, I'm providing an illustration of that case.

[image: The case when we need to extend the given line]

Any hints or ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: "Extrapolation" ? (evident origin : "extra-pole-action" :) )

Comment: @JeanMarie I don't think that's accurate but boy, that's fun!

Comment: One essential surveying task is "to prolong a straight line forward from an existing point."

Answer (score -1):

[image]

One of the admissible concepts/words is ***Extension***. Let OA be the given segment required to be extended.

Construct a regular hexagon around center O with a compass until diametrically opposite point G is reached. Choose any point on OD which is an extension of straight line AO.

If a larger ***extension*** is desired, continue the construction further down.

Comment: So how exactly does this give a name for such an operation?

Comment: Not really an economical way to extend a line, given the method already given in the post.

Comment: @Rusurano: Added emphasis on the word *extension*.